# How does .vimrc relate to ~/.config/nvim/init.lua?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, ex-mode, lua

When I heard neovim had a "native language client", I wanted to trying moving it. Previously, I was using a language server loaded through [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). This was always problematic. When I looked at the documentation for neovim's native language server it pointed me to the [official `nvim-lspconfig` repository](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig). What they suggest is a configuration they provide that *"suggested keymaps for the most commonly used language server functions, and manually triggered completion with omnifunc ()."* However, this configuration they provide is in Lua.

Now it seems that this configuration should be at `~/.config/nvim/init.lua`. But it also seems that much of the Lua API can be used to move Ex commands into init.lua, ie., that there is an overlap.

Should I rewrite commands in `.vimrc` into Lua? Is there a performance benefit for this? How should I divide work amongst both of these files? My old vimrc used to contain the plugin manager and loader. It seems now this is in Lua? If this has moved to Lua, what else should move to Lua?